# Azure Logic Apps: Retrieving Blob Body for a Salesforce Attachment Record

Tags: azure, salesforce, blob, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to extract the BLOB content of an attachment in Salesforce and save it in my Azure BLOB storage with the Salesforce connector in Azure Logic Apps.

So far I'm doing the following...
(1) Use 'Execute Query' connector to get the Id of the object that has the attachment
(2) Use 'Execute Query' connector to get the Id of the attachment using the Id of the parent object above
(3) Use 'Get Record by External ID' to get the attachment object using it's ID obtained above

This gets me the 'Body' attribute '/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment/001Z000000ZZzZz/body' but I can't find any connectors that I can use to retrieve the content using this body.

Has anyone had success retrieving BLOB content from Salesforce using the connectors in Azure Logic Apps?

Comment: I'm able to get the BLOB content in Postman by following the steps here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm but would like to do the same with the Salesforce connectors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error I don't think it's possible to do this with the salesforce connectors in an Azure Logic App. I was able to get the attachment by writing an Azure Function in C# using the salesforce nuget package and using the method GetBlobAsync.